# python different length for same unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I found something really weird about unicode, in my understanding, if I u"" + "string", the type will be unicode, but why are their length different?

```
print len(u''+'New York\u200b')
14
print type(u''+'New York\u200b')
<type 'unicode'>
print len(u'New York\u200b')
9
print type(u'New York\u200b')
<type 'unicode'>
```

I also tried to get rid of \u200b, which I think it is unicode

```
text = u'New York\u200b'
print text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
New York
text = u''+'New York\u200b'
print text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
New York\u200b
```

Also got different result, I am really confused!
btw, I am using python 2.7, is it the time to change to 3.3?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: in `u''+'New York\u200b'`, `'New York\u200b'` is not unicode, therefore, the \u200b is ignored. This is inconsistent with your second result, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> (u''+'New York\u200b').encode('utf-8')
'New York\\u200b'
```

As you can see, since `'New York\u200b'` is **not** a unicode string, the `\u` escape *doesn't* have any special meaning and it is interpreted literally, i.e. as the sequence of ASCII characters `\` `u` `2` `0` `0` `b`, hence the string has length `14`. The `u''` only converts the string to unicode, but it does **not** cause a re-interpretation of the contents. Putting the `u` before the literal makes python interpret it as an escape, hence as a single character, hence the string is length 9.

In your second example:

> ```
> text = u''+'New York\u200b'
> print text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
> New York\u200b
> ```

Here the `.encode` does **not** modify the characters in the string, it only converts from `unicode` to `str`.

It's probably clearer if you *print* the contents of the two strings

```
>>> print(u'New York\u200b')  # note: \u200b interpreted as unicode character
New York
>>> print(b'New York\u200b'.decode('ascii'))
New York\u200b
```

Or if you prefer to see an actual unicode representation try with code point 9731:

```
>>> print(u'New York\u2603')
New York☃
>>> print(b'New York\u2603'.decode('ascii'))
New York\u2603
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So u'' only convert whatever in the quote from str to unicode, but not the str it is appending to, and make the type to unicode for the whole thing?

Comment: @amstree Yes. When you concatenate two strings, python does *not* interpret the escapes. The escapes are interpreted *only* when creating the string *literals*. Concatenation operations treat all characters the same. If you want to interpret the contents of a string you should use the `unicode-escape` encoding. For example: `b'\u2603'.decode('unicode-escape')` is `u'\u2603'`(or `'☃'`) while `b'\u2603'.decode('ascii')` is the string `u'\\u2603'`. The latter is a one-character string, the former is a 6 character string made of the characters ```\``` `u` `2` `6` `0` `3`.

Answer (score 0):

'New York\u200b' is a non-unicode string of length 14.
(You append it to u'' string, but it itself is not unicode yet.)
u'New York\u200b' is a unicode string of length 9.

Comment: This is a restatement of the question, not an answer.